# How to remove duplicates and display unique values in backend (i.e. run time). while run this code what we ll give specific column that is removed

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pandas

```
import re
import pandas as pd

# my imports
from job_processing.utils import *

def get_duplication(rule):
    try:
        return re.compile(rule.duplication, re.UNICODE)
    except re.error:
        raise re.error

def run_duplication(rule, df, column):

    cols = dict()
    cols["dirty"] = get_column_name(df, column)
    cols["clean"] = get_unique_column_name(df, "clean")

    # add a new column for the clean data
    df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=0, keep='first'),cols["clean"]] = df[cols["dirty"]]

    # return the dirty dataframe with the clean column appended to the end...
    return df, df[cols["clean"]].dropna().unique()
```

my orginal file

```
       0       1   2   3   4  
0  Jason  Miller  42   4  25 
1   Tina     Ali  36  31  57 
2   Jake  Milner  24   2  62 
3  Jason  Miller  42   4  25 
4   Jake  Milner  24   2  62 
5    Amy   Cooze  73   3  70 
6  Jason  Miller  42   4  25 
7  Jason  Miller  42   4  25 
8   Jake  Milner  24   2  62 
9   Jake  Miller  42   4  25
```

My requirement like below.

```
       0       1   2   3   4
0  Jason  Miller  42   4  25
1   Tina     Ali  36  31  57
2   Jake  Milner  24   2  62
5    Amy   Cooze  73   3  70
```

Pls can review it and suggest me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=[0])
print (df1)
       0       1   2   3   4
0  Jason  Miller  42   4  25
1   Tina     Ali  36  31  57
2   Jake  Milner  24   2  62
5    Amy   Cooze  73   3  70

df = pd.concat([df, df1])
print (df)
       0       1   2   3   4
0  Jason  Miller  42   4  25
1   Tina     Ali  36  31  57
2   Jake  Milner  24   2  62
3  Jason  Miller  42   4  25
4   Jake  Milner  24   2  62
5    Amy   Cooze  73   3  70
6  Jason  Miller  42   4  25
7  Jason  Miller  42   4  25
8   Jake  Milner  24   2  62
9   Jake  Miller  42   4  25
0  Jason  Miller  42   4  25
1   Tina     Ali  36  31  57
2   Jake  Milner  24   2  62
5    Amy   Cooze  73   3  70
```